# Can you use a URL to embed an image inline in MVCMailer

Tags: image, embed, mvcmailer

In looking at the MVCMailer step by step, I see that you can embed images inline using cid in the HTML.

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

I see the code that talks about embedding:

```
@Html.InlineImage("logo", "Company Logo")


var resources = new Dictionary<string, string>();
resources["logo"] = logoPath;
PopulateBody(mailMessage, "WelcomeMessage", resources);
```

My question is rather than use a path within the site like:

```
resources["logo"] = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/logo.png");
```

Can I somehow get at images I have in the Azure Cloud or S3 Cloud where I have plenty of space?

Please let me know if there is a way to get the image from some other source than the server the MVC mailer is running on.

Thanks,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

In Server.MapPath(my_path), my_path, specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory. Server.MapPath is related with local FileSystemObject so in that case it will look for the file (you pass as parameter) in a location within local web server. More info is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=VS.90).aspx

So if you image is located at http://azure_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/your_public_container/image_name.jpg, the passing it to Server.MapPath() will not work as this is not a location in local file system. I tried and found that it will not accept and I also try to tweak a few way but no success. IF you can change the code behind and which can access the resources from a URL then it will work  otherwise not.